# About MaOS Python building applications, OS.GETCWD () to return data problems

Tags: python, macos, pyinstaller

This is my code, and its role is to output the current working directory.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print os.getcwd()
```

I packaged the script with pyinstaller, the following is the packaging command.

```
pyinstaller -D demo.py
```

Get the /dist/demo directory.

No matter at any location, double click to run /dist/demo/demo file.

The results returned were all /Users/myname.

However, in Windows/Linux, return to result is double-click the directory where the files are running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no assurance that `os.getcwd()` will be the same in every environment. It depends on how the process was spawned.

If you want the directory in which the executable is located, you might get a better result using `os.path.dirname(__file__)` or `os.path.dirname(sys.executable)`.

Comment: Thank you, this is a good way to do it. However, because all the places where I return to work directory in my project are using os.getcwd (), it is very difficult to modify them. I want to find a more convenient way

Comment: You can use `os.chdir(path)` to explicitly set the pwd to the above path.